# How to find bitness of Outlook in WIX bootstrapper?

Tags: outlook, wix, ms-office

I need to install applications to a PC depending on the bitness of installed MS Office package. How can I check for the bitness of MS office package within the WIX bootstrapper assembly ? I have multiple package groups within my bootstrap project.

Comment: Most likely registry searches are needed for this. I don't know what they are but I imagine 64-bit Outlook writes to the 64-bit registry location while 32-bit to the 32-bit location. HKLM\SOFTWARE\[32bitlocation]\Microsoft Outlook\ or something like that is my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value at either of these keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook\Bitness
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook\Bitness

If you need to use the registry to determine the version of Outlook, look at:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Outlook.Application\CurVer

Comment: I already know these data can be fetched from the registry as you have mentioned. My question is how to use these paths to determine the bitness within the bootstrapper project. How these paths can be used ?

Comment: I don't follow - what's the issue with reading the registry in your bootstrapper project?

Comment: The result for "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Outlook.Application\CurVer" is something like this " Outlook.Application.15" how can I use the value to get only the numerical value and include it in another path as a variable for another registry path ?

Comment: Can't you use code to strip out the number at the end and retrieve the values from the registry keys I named by looking for them with the appropriate version number?

Comment: I am sorry I am a total newbie to WIX. How is it possible to use any code within bootstrapper ?any reference articles ?

Comment: I haven't extended Wix to that extent yet, but I imagine it has an interface you can inherit from to add custom code for bootstrapper scenarios - just like you can with Windows Installer projects. Maybe I'm wrong - I'd be searching for the answer myself - which is often with Wix because it can be damn complicated!

Comment: Okay, so what would be a reliable option to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: They recommend Wix Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions in the answers to this question - seems legit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342679/how-to-use-vs-installer-class-in-a-custom-action

Comment: Okay. Ill check this. Keep on rocking eric ;)